# Job Import Plugin doesn’t import folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m currently trying to import jobs from a server running on AWS to a new server running on GCP Kubernetes.

I already set up the [Job Import Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-import-plugin/) version 3.4 on the new server.

When I tried to import the jobs it worked when it was only 1 job.

**But when I imported a Folder with jobs and folders inside, the Folder is imported with nothing inside.**

Old Server: Jenkins version 2.127

New Server: Jenkins version 2.289.2

Any help?

Comment: You checked ☑️ _Search into folders_, right?

Comment: There appear to packaged documentation, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061186/598141) seems to document  it well. From a Jenkins perspective, a Folder is just another JOB type, same as Freestyle, Pipeline, etc. So, am assuming import the folder just imports the job "Folder". Then you can import the jobs (pipeline|freestyle) within the folder.

Comment: Also see: [JENKINS-64121](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64121) and [53902](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53902), and [51746](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51746).

Comment: @Ian W As mentioned there's an option on the `$JENKINS_URL/job-import/` page which sounds logical doing exactly this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plugin appears to provide NO documentation, either in the [legacy wiki page](https://web.archive.org/web/20181006022512/https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin), the [Plugins page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-import-plugin/), or the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-import-plugin). This [answer from @valdeci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061186/598141) does a good job of providing usage instructions.

**TL;DR** : You have to do it in phases; folders, then jobs in each folder. The recurse into folders just does not work well.

**ISSUE** : Jenkins treats a Folder object as just another Job type, similar to Freestyle Job and Pipeline Job (hence the "New Item" presentation). It's evident the plugin does not handle folders and jobs inside folders intuitively. It also does not provide direct feedback to the user (errors are in the jenkins.log).

**CONTEXT** : Using Jenkins 1.121.3, plus job-import-plugin-3.3,folders-6.5.1 worked as expected, as long as you picked the folder and the nested jobs at the same time.

There are a [number of open issues](https://issues.jenkins.io/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20job-import-plugin) for the plugin, including:
JENKINS-64121: Jenkins ImportPlugin - Error '/' unsafe character
and [53902](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-53902) (The folder alone is copied, but not the job present inside the folder). I don't know when the behaviour changed, but is possible however to to import the jobs.

**Configuration/ Setup** :

The following is verified Jenkins-2.289.3, with job-import-plugin-3.4,folders-6.16.

Assume you installed, configured the job-import plugin (left image), clicked on the Job Import plugin button (or `${JENKINS_URL}/job-import` (right image) ):

[image: Job Import plugin dialogs]

You have empty target structure and a source structure:

```
JobInRoot
AFolder
AFolder/JobInFolder
```

**FAILURE OUTCOME** :

If you click **Query!**, the response will be `JobInRoot` and `AFolder`
Select both and it will import the `JobInRoot` AND `AFolder`, but not its contents. That's because it just imported the two Job items (Freestyle job item and Folder job item); it does not recursively import the jobs inside the folder.

> JobInRoot SUCCESS
> AFolder   SUCCESS

If you tick `[ X ] Search into folders` and click **Query!** and the response will be all three items. Selecting all three items and **Import!**, you result in:

> JobInRoot SUCCESS
> AFolder   SUCCESS
> JobInFolder   FAILED - ‘/’ is an unsafe character

**WORKAROUND SOLUTION** :

1. As shown above, Import the Folder `AFolder` first.
2. Run Job Import plugin again, but set **RemoteFolder** to [ `job/AFolder` ], then **Query!**. *This is to work around the unsafe "/" character issue and the poor plugin handling of folders. You'll now see the nested jobs inside `AFolder`.*
3. Set `Copy to folder [ AFolder ]`, select `JobInFolder`, **Import!**

> JobInFolder SUCCESS

and the job is actually in `AFolder/JobInFolder`

3a. To handle nested folders (eg: L1Folder/L2Folder/L3Folder/jobInFolder3) into nested folders, again iterate, but each level needs the "job/” prefix inserted, ie: **RemoteFolder** [ `job/L1Folder/job/L2Folder/job/L3Folder ...` ]. Do not prepend the rooturl, just from the "job/": the qualified itemByFullName-ish.

3b. If you wish to copy nested jobs to the root folder, you must set `Copy to folder [ / ]`, or you will get:

> JobInFolder FAILED null

There are probably more nuances, but this approach should help migrate most items. Have not tested options [ ] Install required plugins or [ ] Override existing jobs.

Comment: That's a great workaround thanks @IAN-W
In my case I have this:
```
JobInRoot
AFolder
AFolder/**BFolder**/JobInFolder
```

I can import BFolder but I wan't to copy to the AFolder but when I write the path to the folder before making the import it fails.

Comment: If I understand, the problem is nested folders (eg: L1Folder/L2Folder/jobInFolder2). Again iterate, but each level needs the "job/” prefix inserted, ie: **RemoteFolder** [ job/L1Folder/job/L2Folder/job/L3Folder ... ] to set the correct source location to avoid the unsafe "/" problem.

Comment: Yes I did that. The problem is importing those jobs to the correct location instead of the root folder.
But I realize that you mention that is a problem in your first answer.

Comment: The "Copy to folder" must exist and you must set the value to match the RemoteFolder, but w/o "job/" in value., ie: "L1Folder/L2Folder/L3Folder"

Comment: I tried that but it keeps show a **FAILED - null**

Comment: I was writing the URL from the Folder and not the Folder name. Now it worked!
Thanks a lot

Comment: I have the same error "Failed - null". What do you mean saying "I was writing the URL from the Folder and not the Folder name"? I think I use the folder name, but still "Failed - null" error @jbacelo

Comment: Never mind, I created a parent folder in the target server, so for me, I need to put /parentFolder/AFolder in "Copy to folder". I was using AFolder there. that causes the Failed-null issue

Comment: I am getting a completely different issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-40577 a class cast exception, I tried this method and at least I am able to import now. I still have to keep the import count low

Answer (score 0):

At least on our Cloudbees Jenkins server, the "Remote Folder" needs to be in the format "job/AWS%20Jobs/" with no leading slash, job, a trailing slash, and encoded e.g. spaces are %20. Then hit Query.

Then on the job selection page, you can put them into an existing folder. And because Jenkins is wildly inconsistent, here the folder name should be in the format "AWS Jobs" instead of the above.